# Are long path behavior per app can be enable via the manifest?

Tags: winapi

despite what is MSDN documentation [say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#maxpath) :

> You can also enable the new long path behavior per app via the
>   manifest:

in test i found that this is not a true. *all test done on win10 1607.14393.447(and 14393.0) x64*

when i test exe with and without manifest, i discover that manifest have no any effect for `CreateFileW`, `CreateDirectoryW`, (no sence test more function - why i explain later)
really when `LongPathsEnabled` is 1 in registry - long paths worked (*without `\\?\` prefix*). when it 0 - not worked, even if `longPathAware` `true` in manifest. (code below)

need understand next:

- all file function in kernel work only with `NT-paths`
- so before call kernel we need convert `Win32-path` no `NT-path`
- for path transformations exist some close functions
  `RtlDosPathNameTo*NtPathName*` in `ntdll`
- all transformations `Win32`->`NT` path done centrally in this functions,
  but not direct in `CreateFileW`, `FindFirstFileW`, 
  `GetCompressedFileSizeW`...  (other behavior would be extremely
  illogical)
- so really enough test 1,2 function, but not all under article (but if
  somebody not believe and want - let test :) )
- all this `kernel32` (and `kernelbase`) api take `Win32-path` and
  convert it to `NT` here - so no any different - are say
  `GetFileAttributesW` called direct from native c/c++ code or from
  managed runtime or app container - result will be the same
- ALL dependent only from `RtlDosPathNameTo*NtPathName*` internal
  implementation

`ntdll` now implement and export 2 new API

```
BOOLEAN NTAPI RtlIsLongPathAwareProcessByManifest();
BOOLEAN NTAPI RtlAreLongPathsEnabled();
```

`RtlAreLongPathsEnabled` - looks only in registry (on first call) `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem @ LongPathsEnabled` cache result in static var and return true when `LongPathsEnabled != 0`. this function called from `RtlDosPathNameTo*NtPathName*` when Win32 path exceeds `MAX_PATH` and only if long paths enabled - path is converted, otherwise `STATUS_NAME_TOO_LONG` returned

`RtlIsLongPathAwareProcessByManifest` - looks only in application manifest (by call `RtlQueryActivationContextApplicationSettings(0, 0, L"http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings", L"longPathAware");`) when it first time called and again cache result in local static BOOLEAN. 
if i not skip something - this function never called from `ntdll` and called from `kernebase.dll` only from one place - `GetTempPathW`. so really result of `RtlIsLongPathAwareProcessByManifest` can have effect only for `GetTempPathW` result.

but when test this - i view that at all **bug in current windows builds** here - if length of `TMP` environment variable (or `TEMP`, etc.. but `TMP` queried first) exceeded `MAX_PATH` queried `RtlAreLongPathsEnabled` and `RtlIsLongPathAwareProcessByManifest` and if both returned true (so here `AND` logic) - system try got this long `TMP` path, but mistake with buffer size on one `WCHAR` - as result we hang in infinite loop - [ *- > `RtlAllocateHeap` -> `STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL` -> `RtlFreeHeap` -> `RtlAllocateHeap` -> *]

**are somebody can test and confirm or refute this ? not pass link to documentation, but really test**.

code which i use for test (with and without correct manifest - confirmed by `RtlIsLongPathAwareProcessByManifest` result)

```
BOOL CreateFolder(LPCWSTR lpPathName)
{
    return CreateDirectoryW(lpPathName, 0) || GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS;
}

void LPT()
{
    // check manifest and registry

    BOOLEAN bByManifest = 0, bLongPathsEnabled = 0;

    if (HMODULE hmod = GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll"))
    {
        BOOLEAN (NTAPI * RtlIsLongPathAwareProcessByManifest)();
        BOOLEAN (NTAPI * RtlAreLongPathsEnabled)();

        if (*(FARPROC*)&RtlIsLongPathAwareProcessByManifest = GetProcAddress(hmod, "RtlIsLongPathAwareProcessByManifest"))
        {
            bByManifest = RtlIsLongPathAwareProcessByManifest();
        }

        if (*(FARPROC*)&RtlAreLongPathsEnabled = GetProcAddress(hmod, "RtlAreLongPathsEnabled"))
        {
            bLongPathsEnabled = RtlAreLongPathsEnabled();
        }
    }

    WCHAR name[128], path[0x8000], *c;

    if (bLongPathsEnabled && bByManifest)
    {
        // hung test in GetTempPathW

        __stosw((PUSHORT)path, 'x', MAX_PATH + 1);
        path[MAX_PATH + 1] = 0;

        if (SetEnvironmentVariable(L"TMP", path))
        {
            // hung here in infinite loop by windows error

            // ---> buffer allocated on sizeof(WCHAR) less than required, 
            // |    got STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL
            // | -< free buffer
            GetTempPathW(RTL_NUMBER_OF(path), path);// never return :)
        }
    }

    if (!SHGetFolderPath(0, CSIDL_PROFILE , 0, 0, path))
    {
        *name = '\\';
        __stosw((PUSHORT)name + 1, '3', RTL_NUMBER_OF(name) - 2);
        name[RTL_NUMBER_OF(name) - 1] = 0;

        c = path + wcslen(path);

        int n = 4;
        do 
        {
            memcpy(c, name, sizeof(name));
            c += RTL_NUMBER_OF(name) - 1;

            if (!CreateFolder(path))
            {
                break;
            }

        } while (--n);

        if (!n)
        {

            wcscpy(c, L"\\1.txt");

            HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(path, FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, 0);

            if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                CloseHandle(hFile);
                return ;
            }
        }
    }

    GetLastError();
}
```